# How can I make my password fields always empty?

Tags: forms, passwords

I have a form field where users can change their passwords, but if they set their settings to remember passwords, their password shows up. Is there a way to make the field always empty? So that they always have to type their password.

```
<label for="oldpassword" class="styled">Old password:</label>
<input type="password" id="oldpassword" name="oldpassword"/><br />
```

Comment: This is **very** bad practice: if they want to remember the password, let them.

Comment: This isn't for logging in. This is more for when they want to change their passwords.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could clear the old password shortly after the page loads.

Using jQuery:

```
setTimeout(
    function() { $(':password').val(''); },
    1000  //1,000 milliseconds = 1 second
);
```

Comment: specially for use of type attribute in selector, new thing to learn

Comment: Because there needs to be a delay before the password is cleared — at least one second as SLaks illustrates — I initially display the field with the opacity set to 0, and then animate back to 1 after the value is cleared. IMO it looks better than having the character bullets appear and disappear.

Answer (score 5):

Use:
`autocomplete="new-password"` attribute in the password input

Answer (score 2):

nope. you cannot handle this browser behaviour.

Comment: Technically, this is true (even 8 years later) and worth crediting. You can clear the field after the browser inserts a password, but you can't "make the field always empty".

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="password" name="my_password_field" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("input[type=password]").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

Password:- <input type="password" name="name" placeholder="Enter your password" ***autocomplete="new-password"*** class="class" id="myInput">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).